# How to run this conditional execution in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to assign a value to a tensor only once, and keep it untouched in all later executions. In other words,  I would like to implement something like the following:

```
x = tf.cond(tf.equal(x_ready, 0), ComputeX(), tf.no_op)
```

This of course will not work, since tf.no_op does not return a tensor. So is there is any easy way of implementing an equivalent to the following C++ code in Tensorflow?

```
x_ready = false;
if (!x_ready) {
  x = ComputeX();
  x_ready = true;
}  // and there is no "else" branch
```

Note that I don't wish to implement it in the following way:

```
x = tf.cond(tf.equal(x_ready, 0), ComputeX(), tf.identity(x))
```

since "x" is not declared before this statement. If seems Tensorflow is inflexible for single-branch conditional executions - you always have to provide two funcitons fn1, fn2 for both "true" and "false" cases, even if fn2 is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is not a procedural programming language, it is a graph programming language.  So you do have to think about things a bit differently.

From a graph evaluation perspective, you either use the variable `x` downstream in the graph or not.  So, if you are actually using `x`, it would have to be computed first (you have to initialize it).  `tf.identity` is necesary to do this.

You have not really explained what you are trying to accomplish, but if `x` depends on `ComputeX()`, and `ComputeX()` does not happen until something else happens, the graph evaluation would have taken care of this order dependency already.  (Graph evaluation order is done with topological sort.)

If you truly have needs to establish dependencies, use [tf.control_dependencies()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#control_dependencies)